# How to decompose arbitrary gates in Qiskit?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, entanglement

I have been exploring quantum computing, I have no idea of decomposing arbitrary gates in Qiskit. Can someone help me with an example?

Comment: See answer here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/how-do-i-build-a-gate-from-a-matrix-on-qiskit

Comment: The long discussion about this is in response to question 4975 (link added as comment above)